# Hero image not working on mozilla

Tags: html, css, image, background, background-image

My hero image is working on every browser but not in Mozilla and I am not sure why this is happening since I am using some pretty standard code that normally works for me.

This is my CSS for the full background header image:

```
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height:100vh;
  padding: 100px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: url(../img/intro-bg.jpg) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
```

And this is the site live: http://www.conlamochilaalhombro.com

Thanks so much!

Comment: "Mozilla" — Do you mean Firefox? [Mozilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Application_Suite) hasn't had an update for a decade.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question. Your HTML is quite important here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Simple Solution

Remove `height: 100%;` from `.intro`.

### Alternative Solution

***» Just showing another way to center text/content.***

Get rid of `display: table;` on `.introp` and `display: table-cell;` on `.intro-body`. Then center `.intro-body` like this:

```
.introp {
    position: relative;
}
.intro-body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate( -50%, -50% );
}
```